# Face recognition/matching for login system

Tags: android, swift, opencv, tensorflow, augmented-reality

I am digging web to find the proper guidelines to implement the face recognition.
I want to make a system which logins by recognising the face.

I have explored the OpenCV, MLKit etc.

Few things I want are,

Android and iOS both should be sync with each other.
One thing I definitely know is that I need to take the help of Server to make it synced.

But how to handle Models of faces, How android and iOS can access and authorise same face.?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to determine what you'll use.

If you want to use machine learning there are so many options for that like OpenCV. Here is an example: [OpenCV Face Recognition](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/24/opencv-face-recognition/)

If you want to use deep learning you can use Tensorflow. There are so many articles about that. i.e. [Tensorflow Face Recognition](https://missinglink.ai/guides/tensorflow/tensorflow-face-recognition-three-quick-tutorials/)

Comment: You're welcome. But you should write the algorith on your own. Because we can't know your application

Comment: Totally agree with you sir, My basic purpose was to take the right path before doing anything.  Going with native SDK  both iOS-Android does not allow us to be sync with each other. Right now I have the plan to make all on the server-side. Any suggestion?

Comment: Actually you can make it on the server side with so many languages. i.e. you can use OpenCV with python, node.js, .Net, etc. If you have VPS or VDS you can use it with so many languages. It's same with the Tensorflow. But if you want to make these processes on the phone: if it's Android, you can use Tensorflow with Java, if it's iOS, you can use Tensorflow with Objective-C. If you want to develope with ReactNative, you can use both OpenCV and Tensorflow with JavaScript. Even if you want to work on the webview application these libraries are available to JavaScript on the browser.

Comment: Also I've added some references to my answer. You can implement these codes to any language

Answer (score 0):

On iOS you can simply use FaceID where it's available:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/logging_a_user_into_your_app_with_face_id_or_touch_id

Any iOS device that doesn't support FaceID can't do a secure enough scan of a user's face and shouldn't use that as it's principal form of login. The vast majority of Android phones aren't secure enough and the ones that do have their own implementation.

Does your system handle sensitive data like medical records, bank transaction or similar?

Comment: Thanks  , No there is no sensitive data. It’s s like school attendance system.

Comment: iOS native Face ID would not allow me to log in outside of the iPhone (e.g Anrdoid). Not even other iPhones.

Comment: True, it will fall back to PIN or fingerprint. I would always recommend to use the built-in authentication unless it's not about authentication but recognizing people in images, in that case a library would work well enough